# ember-data relationships not working

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Trying to figure out how to use relationships and it just is not working.

```
// Data
{
    "apps": {
        "-AFCH5-Kvkc_nfQxnpZ8": {
            "name": "Leap Day",
            "playLink": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nitrome.leapday",
            "price": "0.00",
            "like": 0,
            "show": "-SFCH5-Kvkc_nfQxnpZ8",
            "provider": "-PFCH5-Kvkc_nfQxnpZ8",
            "imageUrl": "https://www.google.com/url?q=https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/5oR-jbrmKNWqdWQnwrDjPD2PJUJekGK_BUAQOjKD3GuJRTk2MLVzuU2HJ0wyY2BYPsdS%3Dw300-rw&sa=D&ust=1464126095843000&usg=AFQjCNH0RSH6_0bA_EUqnZaldtUxCH1fAw"
        },
        "-AFCH5-Kvkc_nfQxnpZ9": {
            "name": "Gangfort",
            "playLink": "https://www.google.com/url?q=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id%3Dcom.gangfort.game.android&sa=D&ust=1464126095844000&usg=AFQjCNFSTZ1p_uBvIHYw97c29XwJU3gEjw",
            "price": "1.99",
            "like": 0,
            "show": "-SFCH5-Kvkc_nfQxnpZ8",
            "provider": "-PFCH5-Kvkc_nfQxnpZ8",
            "imageUrl": "https://www.google.com/url?q=https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/DV5mFhDQ2ADEbiF0S4cxL313JDqRazy9et7Etky5WtH7gxsm9DvbHhb52N0MH1swgfzR%3Dw300-rw&sa=D&ust=1464126095844000&usg=AFQjCNEymzxjrdN8wwL4qN40w5i8i9MlPw"
        }
    },
    "shows": {
        "-SFCH5-Kvkc_nfQxnpZ8": {
            "number": 432,
            "name": "Google I/O Secrets Revealed",
            "date": "05/22/2016",
            "app": ["-AFCH5-Kvkc_nfQxnpZ8", "-AFCH5-Kvkc_nfQxnpZ9"],
            "url": "http://podnutz.com/aaa432/"
        }
    },
    "providers": {
        "-PFCH5-Kvkc_nfQxnpZ8": {
            "firstName": "Steve",
            "lastName": "McLaughlin",
            "nick": "D2d",
            "app": ["-AFCH5-Kvkc_nfQxnpZ8", "-AFCH5-Kvkc_nfQxnpZ9"]
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the app model
    import Model from 'ember-data/model';
    import attr from 'ember-data/attr';
    import { belongsTo } from 'ember-data/relationships';

```
export default Model.extend({
  name: attr('string'),
  playLink: attr('string'),
  price: attr('string'),
  like: attr('number'),
  show: belongsTo('show', {
    async: true
  }),
  provider: belongsTo('provider', {
    async: true
  }),
  imageUrl: attr('string')
});
```

Here is the show model

```
import Model from 'ember-data/model';
import attr from 'ember-data/attr';
import { hasMany } from 'ember-data/relationships';

export default Model.extend({
  number: attr('number'),
  name: attr('string'),
  date: attr('date'),
  apps: hasMany('app'),
  url: attr('string')
});
```

Here is my route

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return this.store.findAll('app');
  }
});
```

Here is what the ember console looks like

[image: Ember Console]

So the problem is when I try to access the show object in my template, its not coming up

```
{{#each model as |show|}}
    {{app.show.name}}
{{/each}}
```

Update

From the looks of the markup it seems like something is working here

[image]

Here is the console when I log app.show

[image]

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: Thanks, forgot to add that part. Updated post

Comment: Please add also your router so that we see how the 'model' property is set (model() hook). According to the Ember console it seems the show instance is present, my guess is that your model is actually the app instance.
try this:
`{{#if model.show}}
    {{model.show.name}}
{{/if}}`

Comment: Added route to original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `apps: hasMany('app')` reference in your `show` model is overwriting your relationship defined in the shows model.

Answer (score 0):

you are not iterating through each app model in template.
it should be like that

```
{{#each model as |app|}}
    {{app.show.name}}
{{/each}}
```

your each loop is like that  `{{#each model as |show|}}`

Comment: All your asking me to do is change the variable name. Not sure how this would solve my issue

Comment: Show is defined as a single instance in the app model, 1 app has max 1 show according to such definition (belongTo vs. hasMany)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{{#each model as |app|}}
  {{#if app.show}}
   {{app.show.name}}
  {{/if}}
{{else}}
   Loading apps...
{{/each}}
```

Here I would recommend taking advantage of [ember-promise helpers](https://github.com/fivetanley/ember-promise-helpers) since the relation between an app and a show is asynchronous:

```
{{#each model as |app}}
  {{#if (await app.show)}}
   {{get (await app.show) 'name'}}
  {{/if}}
{{else}}
   Loading apps...
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Updated (there was a typo + I added a section for ember-promise-helpers)

Comment: What happens when you use `{{app.show}}` instead of `{{app.show.name}}` on the line 3 in my post?

Comment: Same result as the last

Comment: But do you see the ID or the {{if}} is never reached? Can you use debugging helpers liks {{log}} to give us more info?